# Regex express begin & end specific words[No duplicate]

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex represent 'recognizes words that begin and end in "t".'

I think that the below code is true.

```
var re = /^t+t*t$/
```

But it shows 'false'

e.g.

```
re.test('triplet')

re.test('thought')

re.test('that')
```

why doesn't my answer solve the above string?

and what is the proper regex?

Comment: `t+` means multiple literal `t` characters. Then `t*` means zero or more literal `t`'s followed by a literal `t`. So you have left no room for any other characters than at least two literal `t`s. If what inbetween these `t`s need to be letters, then try a character class of `[a-z]*` instead of `+t*`. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/Kgw3QQ/2)

Comment: @JvdV That's a great site to learn regex. Thanks, man. God bless you.

Comment: Using code you could also check the first and the last char instead of using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, as pointed out in the comments.

A naive approach could be to check if the entire word starts with t, has any number of any character and then ends with t:

```
var re = /^t.*t$/
```

of course, you could also limit the "middle" character to letters:

```
var re = /^t[a-z]*t$/
```

However, neither of these approaches check for a word that is a single "t" character. If this is a valid usecase, you'll have to handle it explicitly, e.g.:

```
var re = /^(t[a-z]*t|t)$/
```

Comment: Aha! It doesn't check a single "t" so, It needs to handle explicitly such that. That's great. Thanks, man.

Comment: In case of allowing a single t, maybe `^t([a-z]*t)?$` is more resource-friendly?

Comment: @JvdV nice one!